# How to wake up from a long sleep in bash and exit when an IP becomes unavailable?

Tags: bash, timeout, sleep

I have a script that uses **timeout** command to check for the availability of an IP and then if the status is 0 then runs a block of code which blocks ports to prevent incoming traffic. I have shared some of the problematic code below:

```
timeout 10 bash -c "</dev/tcp/$IP/5060"
        status=$( echo $? )
        if [[ $status == 0 ]] ; then
                echo "Primary DC is available..Proceeding to sleep"
                sleep 600
```

The issue is that I want to find a way to exit from the 10 minute sleep if the IP becomes unavailable while in sleep. Is there a way to go in sleep, keep checking for an IPs availability at the same time and exit if it becomes unavailable.

Comment: Can you reformat your code sample to a reproducible example?

Comment: Instead of sleeping for 10 minutes straight, you have to actively check the availability every now and then using a loop or a program like `ping`.

Comment: `timeout 10` does not sleep for 10 minutes

Comment: @jhnc right but `sleep 600` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way IMHO is to not do `sleep 600`, but instead do 600 `sleep 1`s or 60 `sleep 10s` or similar, checking status every time it wakes up, e.g. untested:

```
for (( i=1; i<=60; i++ )); do
    if timeout 10 bash -c "</dev/tcp/$IP/5060"; then
        sleep 10
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

I expect the extra work involved there means that loop would take longer than 10 minutes to run so you might want to reduce `60` to `50` or some other reduced value or take a timestamp from `date` before entering the loop to compare against the timestamp inside the loop and break if it gets to 10 mins or similar if it's important to wait close to exactly 10 minutes.